# Adding multiple Arraylist items into one ArrayList item

Tags: java, arraylist

I have two ArrayLists and want to put a range of 5 items into one item from one ArrayList into the other. My current code for that looks like this:

```
fragenArrayPack.add(fragenArray.get(0) + fragenArray.get(1) + fragenArray.get(2) + fragenArray.get(3) + fragenArray.get(4));
fragenArrayPack.add(fragenArray.get(5) + fragenArray.get(6) + fragenArray.get(7) + fragenArray.get(8) + fragenArray.get(9));
```

This works but is very impractical. Is there a faster/better way to do this?

Comment: i think methods will help you.

Comment: Your question isn't clear at all. What is the type of entries in `fragenArray`, and what is the type of entries in the `fragenArrayPack`? If you want people to **really** help you, you have to enable us by telling us about the problem you intend to solve here. As you might have noticed: when you don't do that, most likely you will only get answers from other new users who are guessing what your problem might be. And who then throw whatever (basic) knowledge of Java they have at you.

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to add them with "+".
May be you will create constructor with 5 objects or simply add with for loop

Comment: is fragenArrayPack String ?

Answer (score 0):

You want something like that

```
public int sumRangeOfArrayList(int startIndex, int lastIndex, ArrayList<Integer> myNumberArrayList) {
    if (startIndex < 0 || lastIndex < 0 || startIndex > myNumberArrayList.size() - 1 || lastIndex > myNumberArrayList.size() - 1 || startIndex > lastIndex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("wrong input");
    }
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = startIndex; i <= lastIndex; i++) {
        sum += myNumberArrayList.get(i);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Beware I did not test my code, I have just put it together. But you want a method like that, which will calculate the sum and is reusable.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your lists contains Integer and you are using Java 8, you can use streams:

```
public static Integer addRange(ArrayList<Integer> list, Integer startingIndex, Integer amount) {
    return list.stream().skip(startingIndex).limit(amount).reduce(0, Integer::sum);
}

fragenArrayPack.add(addRange(fragenArray, 0, 5));
fragenArrayPack.add(addRange(fragenArray, 5, 5));
```

For String concatenation :

```
public static String concatRange(ArrayList<String> list, Integer startingIndex, Integer amount) {
    return list.stream().skip(startingIndex).limit(amount).reduce("", String::concat);
}

fragenArrayPack.add(concatRange(fragenArray, 0, 5));
fragenArrayPack.add(concatRange(fragenArray, 5, 5));
```

And if you want you can parameterize the function to pass to the reduce method and made the method generic